# display the particular item name and item price from input file through command prompt?

Tags: awk, gawk, nawk

```
Chenna Black |1|76.00|Chenna
Chenna White big|1|102.00|Chenna
Chenna White small|1|82.00|Chenna
Dhal-Gram|1|78.00|Dhal
Dhal-Moong|1|76.00|Dhal
Dhal-Orid|1|72.00|Dhal
Dhal-Toor|1|68.00|Dhal
Dhal-Green gram|1|88.00|Dhal
Rajma-Black|1|72.00|Rajma
Rajma-Pink|1|80.00|Rajma
Rice-Basmanthi|1|80.00|Rice
Rice-Boiled|1|42.00|Rice
Rice-Idly|1|33.00|Rice
Rice-IGBasamanthi|1|99.00|Rice
Rice-Karanatka Ponni|1|38.00|Rice
Rice-Nirapara Silky|1|235.00|Rice
Rice-Raw|1|40.00|Rice
Rice-RoastedGram|1|100.00|Rice
```

its my input file. suppose if i check rice item from input file. it will display the rice item and rice item price also.And if i write non -available item from the file like " sugar " item . it will display the "item is not found".

Comment: What's the question?  This will be closed pronto unless you ask a question in the body of the question.  Which items are you trying to check, for example?  What's your input (search item), and what's your expected output?  Are you looking for multiple different names simultaneously?  What have you tried?  Why do you need to use `awk` or a derivative — why not `grep` or one of its variants?  How does the tag `redhawksdr` relate to your question?

Comment: Edit the question — don't add comments!  You'll need to use clear enough English (your comment is not really clear).  You'll need to explain what `maxrate` is.  Think about what you are asking — while what you ask is incoherent, you won't get coherent answers.  Also, you should explain what you've tried...you have tried some ideas, haven't you?  Is the search supposed to be case insensitive?  If so, I'm not convinced `awk` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: It seems a bit funny that the currently accepted answer to a question tagged `awk`, `gawk` and `nawk` is written in Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do it in perl:

```
perl -F"|" -ane 'BEGIN{$f=0}if(/Rice/){print;$f=1}END{print "not found\n" unless($f)}' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v item=Rice '$0 ~ item { i++; print }
                  END       { if (i == 0) print item " not found" }' data
```

If you want selected fields, you'll have to identify what each field contains.  The 1 is presumably the price?  (OK: no, it is fairly unlikely to be the price, but you should not expect us to divine the meaning of the columns in your data; — you should tell us the meanings.)  It is not clear whether the item is in field 1 or field 4 or both.

That is not case-insensitive — if you want case-insensitivity, read the manual for your version of `awk`; it may or may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v item=Rice -F "|" "$0 ~ item {i++; total = total + $3}; END { 
if (i>0) print \"item name\",item,\"NO OF ITEMS\",i,\"total amount \",total; else print \"item not found\"}" datafile
```

output answer:

```
item name Rice NO OF ITEMS 8 total amount 667
```

In my program searching for rice. After that searched for pattern matching form input file. Next I used for counting number of rice items, total is used for total amount's of all rice. Initial item is variable, rice is value to assigned to variable item. Finally it displays the item, count of items, total amount of item.